# Error in loading ViewController- loaded the nib but the view outlet was not set

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

My iOS 5-6 app is crashing after attempting to load a ViewController from a button pushed in one storyboard file (FifthViewController.storyboard) to a separate xib (WebViewController.xib). The exact error message: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "WebViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'`

This error typically appears when view outlets have not been connected or ViewControllers have not been assigned a class. In WebViewController.xib, everything is connected, including the view (you cannot disconnect this, actually) and my web view. My ViewController's class is correctly labeled as WebViewContrller.

Here's my code:

**WebViewController.h**

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSURL *urlToLoad;

- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url;
```

**WebViewController.m**

```
@synthesize webView, urlToLoad;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlToLoad]];
}

- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url {
[self setUrlToLoad:url];
return self;
}
```

**FifthViewController.m** -- this is the VC from where a button is place that calls WebViewController

```
- (IBAction)pushedArts:(id)sender {
WebViewController *wvc = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yahoo.com"]];
[self presentModalViewController:wvc animated:YES];
}
```

[image: image 1][image: image 2]
The images show the connections within WebViewController.xib and its class. Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `-[WebViewController initWithURL:]` method should call `[super initWithNibName:bundle:]` to properly initialize your view controller, including associating the proper nib, etc.

In general, if you write any initializer it has to (directly or indirectly) call the designated initializer of the superclass.

Comment: Changing my init method to: `- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url {

    self = [super initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self setUrlToLoad:url];
    return self;
}` Yields the same error. I think this is barking up the right tree however.

Comment: Wait, your screenshot of WebViewController.xib shows segues. Are you sure that's not actually the storyboard in your screenshot?

Comment: I've changed it since, but WebViewController.xib was actually a storyboard (sorry for mislabeling it).

Comment: Was a storyboard or is a storyboard? If it's a storyboard, is it the same storyboard where you have FifthViewController? If it is not a storyboard any more, please post the actual screenshot of the nib as it is right now.

Comment: It is no longer a storyboard and even when it was, it was a different storyboard. It is now a xib file that is (still) separate from the storyboard that houses all my other view controllers. I'll update the screenshot.

Comment: ok, the class and the outlets you are showing there are for 'File's Owner', yes?

Comment: They are for the view controller, not file's owner. There are no outlets nor classes for file's owner. I'm guessing this is the issue... I changed the class name of F's O to WebViewController, but an outlet is not capable of being connected from "new referencing outlet" to the view. What outlets do I need? Thank you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25487/discussion-between-firoze-lafeer-and-gdyer)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check your nib file, because it is clear for me that the system could not locate your nib file, or the view outlet is not connected. Open your nib file, go to the last tab, and connect your view outlet, as the normal way you should connect other components

Comment: I just included an image in an edit of my question. I believe everything is properly connected. Perhaps an error with my custom initializer within WebViewController.m?